# If you can only secure one wheel when locking bike which wheel is better

Tags: lock, security

When I lock my bike I always lock the front wheel with my bike to the rack since front wheel is easier to remove.  Is this the right choice?

I have only one U-lock so can only secure one wheel, not both.

Comment: Are you thinking of a particular sort of rack? With a long enough D lock and little enough rake (e.g. a compact road frame)  it would be possible to lock the front wheel and frame to something like a [Sheffield stand](https://www.cyclehoop.com/product/home-storage/sheffield-stand/) but in many cases it wouldn't, especially wheel bender racks

Comment: Are you parking your bike in a dangerous/risky area?  Do your wheels have nuts, QRs, or something else securing them?

Comment: That is why I always supplement my heavy metal lock (yes, it rocks \m/ ) with a long cable lock: The cable can secure the wheel that the heavy metal fails to reach. This also provides some protection in depth: The ideal tools for breaking a heavy metal lock and a cable lock are different, so thieves without both are strongly discouraged. Make a point of fixing both locks to something solid, and thieves will most likely just walk by.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I do exactly the same, though it does not to be a heavy D-lock as some are small enough for bolt croppers to get through, and those will mangle a cable with enough effort.

Comment: @ChrisH That's why I said "heavy metal": I meant any type of lock that is best opened with an angle grinder. I did not mean to imply anything about the type of heavy metal. It could be a thick armor chain, bar chain, or D lock.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica plus if you catch someone in the act a chain lock could be useful as thrash metal!

Comment: If I needed an inner tube and was a thief, I'd steal the front. If I needed a rear for its gears, I'd just steal the whole bike. So yes, lock the front. And anywhere you lock up your bike, no matter how it's done, be prepared to replace the whole thing even if you do get a lock that can do both tires, the frame, *and* you [take the speed nuts with you](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/79306/20175).

Comment: @Mazura I may be wrong, but I always get the impression that most thieves want to turn their loot into money, not use it themselves ((semi-)professional thieves). An exception are the thieves that steal a whole bike for a single ride (like riding home after drinking at a pub). Again, these are not interested in specific parts. I guess, the thieves that own and ride a bike themselves are rather rare.

Comment: Somewhat cynical here.  Locks no matter how good, only slow potential thieves will down.  While they may be a deterrent to the more casual so the move on to the easier pray, if someone wants what's yours, they will take it.  Ignoring the inconvenience of your trusty steed going missing, the real reason to lock up is so you can say I did my best to the insurance company.  IMO lock it as best you can but don't worry about going too hard out on locks or procedures etc.  You're really only wasting your time and money

Answer (score 14):

I would lock the rear wheel.

The problem of locking the front wheel with U lock is that there's no way to lock it easily (or at least I can't imagine one). The front wheel is attached to the fork, but the fork doesn't have a closed "loop" so there's no place in the fork where you could lock the front wheel. So if you lock the front wheel, chances are you will find the front wheel locked to the rack, with the rest of the bike and the rear wheel missing.

Also, a typical front wheel is less expensive than a typical rear wheel since rear wheels have slightly more expensive hub (with a freewheel mechanism) and a cassette -- although a dynamo hub could equalize the costs of front and rear wheels. Considering that there are very many options to secure the rear wheel, that's the recommended wheel to secure.

The front wheel obviously could be secured with a separate cable. Carrying a long enough cable could of course be cumbersome. I always ride with my messenger bag and I have found that a cable fits to the messenger bag easily and isn't too heavyweight.

Comment: Even with a dynamo hub I preferentially lock the back wheel (by D-lock) though I also carry a cable lock for the front wheel when commuting, *and* use either a security skewer (tourer) or at least track nuts (hybrid with very old dynamo hub) on the front.  I find a long cable lock preferable to a looped cable; it provides a minor extra deterrent for securing the whole bike, and mine passes through helmet vents. +1

Comment: I think OP is locking the front wheel + frame to the bike rack.

Comment: It is quite possible to lock a front wheel and frame to a sheffield type stand using a U lock. This picture shows how and after a bit of practice I can do this with a much shorter lock than pictured.  https://thebestbikelock.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/lock-bike-2-u-locks.jpg

Comment: @Michael I asked for clarification on that.  It might be possible but it's not always easy

Comment: I agree, I would add that the rear wheel not only is more expensive, but it adds hassle if you have to find a proper replacement,  finding the same cassette might not be that easy.

Answer (score 13):

The most important thing is that the frame is securely locked to a solid object.

If you can also lock one or both wheels it’s nice but I wouldn’t worry too much. The rear wheel is more expensive but also harder to get out.

If you take out one (or both) of the wheels you might be able to lock both wheels + frame to an object with a single long-ish U-lock.

I don’t think single wheels are commonly stolen, just like seatpost+saddle, handlebars or derailleurs are usually not stolen.

It’s different if your wheels (or other components) are very expensive and/or you live in a high-risk area. In that case I’d try to lock as much as possible. For example thread an additional cable lock through the saddle rails, rear wheel, frame and a solid object.

Comment: Stealing seatposts is actually not that uncommon, but I have no idea why anyone would do that. Clarification: I am aware that in many cases when there's a bike locked in a public place with no seatpost, it was actually the owner who took the post as a security measure. But sadly I am aware of cases when the seatpost truly was stolen ...

Comment: @Szabolcs really nice seatposts are not exactly cheap in some parts of the world. Where I live, the nice dropper seatposts found on some more expensive bikes are multiple hundreds of USD by themselves, and the same goes for good carbon seatposts. Combined with a nice saddle, that could be well over a thousand USD in what is one of the easiest parts of a bike to quickly remove, so it’s not hard IMO to see why someone might steal it.

Comment: A nice seatpost + saddle is more like 350€. With MTB dropper posts maybe 450€. But yes, very easy to steal for what they cost. And especially the saddle is compatible with basically all bikes, so somebody might even steal it for their own use (and not just to sell it). If somebody is determined they might even steal the seatpost alone if the saddle is secured with a cable lock.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Those bikes are not left unattended in town. I'm talking about relatively cheap everyday bikes (which is the majority of bikes here). You just go out to have a drink, and when you're back your bike is there but no seatpost ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I would assume just to mess with the person, because people do that.

Comment: @Michael another advantage of dropper post, apart from being a dropper post, is that it's  a lot harder to steal. Once I came back to my bike and noticed multiple bikes nearby were missing their saddles. I don't doubt if my post hadn't been a dropper, it would have been gone too. — What's _ridiculously_ common is stealing of battery-powered lights. At one point I had a really cheap battery headlight _glued_ to the handlebars, with extra wire bracing. Somebody still stole it, apparently with brute force – I doubt the light even worked anymore afterwards.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Should have welded it to your handlebars and then wrapped a wire around it for decoration.

Comment: ...the rear wheel is more expensive AND harder to get out? Aren't both of these arguing for the same thing (locking the rear wheel)?

Comment: @MaxD: No. The front wheel is (usually) very easy to take out but also less expensive (assuming you don’t have an expensive hub dynamo). So low effort to steal but also worth less. On the rear wheel you have to fiddle around with the chain. Depending on how the bike is locked this could be quite the hassle. But the “reward” is higher because rear wheels are usually worth more.

Comment: Once the seat post is fixed at the right height, what's wrong with drilling a small hole right through the frame, and knocking in a roll pin - better than a long threaded bolt and nut. Same idea for the saddle.

Answer (score 11):

Bottom Line:
Nothing is perfect. You need to develop a strategy based on what parts you are willing to replace.

I use a U lock and a steel cable similar to the pictures below and I take my quick release skewers with me.

Here are some suggestions from other sources

According to [one maker of U shaped](http://www.onguardlock.com/how-to-guides) locks this is the best way to lock your bike:
[thread a cable on both wheels then close the loop with a U-lock.](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/51e6e76be4b066098f51193e/1386083853460-GBUMUYZHI8ON8CTQ1YZC/BikeLockUp_CabelUlock.jpg?format=750w)

Here's another version [from another source](https://sfbike.org/news/video-how-to-lock-your-bike/).
[image]

[Kryptonite suggests several options](https://www.kryptonitelock.com/en/proper-lockup-landing/bicycle-lock-up-bike.html) depending on your situation.

1. Frame only - If you can only secure one thing then secure the frame
2. Frame and rear wheel
3. Frame, rear wheel and front wheel using a cable
4. Frame, rear wheel and front wheel using two U shaped locks

Comment: This is an excellent answer because it covers the full spectrum of how much security you want to put in place. There is no universal answer, some bikes are expensive and precious to their owners and need all those locks. My bike lives at the end of the street, secured as described in 1). It's cheap enough that I'm not worried.

Comment: Here is something Interesting I learned in this stack a while ago: *It is sufficient to just lock the rear wheel in the triangle area in order to secure the frame as well.* You cannot (easily) pull the wheel through the triangle.

Comment: Nitpick: The method in the picture is not the best. A better method is to use a real cable lock instead of the cable, securing both frame and front wheel to something solid, independently of the U-lock. That way, breaking the U-lock with an angle grinder won't suffice to take the entire bike.

Answer (score 9):

Interestingly, just locking the back wheel can also secure the frame if you do it in the right position, as shown in [this post](https://www.pinterest.de/pin/228205906088422990/) on pinterest:

[image: rear wheel lock]

You can remove neither wheel nor frame because the wheel does not fit through the triangle; it keeps the frame in place. This is often a lot easier than trying to secure both frame and wheel, which is simply unnecessary, if you think about it. (There is a caveat for expensive bicycles: The wheel is the weak spot here, easy to cut, so if the thief is willing to destroy the back wheel and carry the bike it can be stolen easier than by cutting the lock. But for everyday bicycles it is sufficient protection.)

If that makes anybody feel better: I regularly locked frame and wheel for about 40 years before I learned about this life hack, probably on this site ;-).

Answer (score 6):

Having a U type lock, I'm inclined to, if I really have to, remove the front wheel, put the nuts in my pocket, and secure through the frame, back wheel, and front wheel, to a solid point. By now, the two wheels are next to each other, and there's little left to be removed.

Comment: This a pretty common strategy when using a truck bed rack that anchors via the front fork drop-outs (minus the wheel)

Comment: *Locks keep honest people out.* Help them stay honest by taking the freaking nuts with you, FFS? +1

Answer (score 3):

If assuming that the bike is not equipped with any additional locks, I'd also lock the rear wheel, for reasons already explained in other answers.

But to go a bit further than the initial question, you can also secure wheel individually, and then use your U-lock with the non-secured wheel, or just the frame if both wheels are secured.

The most common one is the "frame lock" for the rear wheel if your frame allows it. It looks like something like the picture below (most don't have a chain attached though). Then you can use your U-lock with the front wheel.

[image: frame lock]

A another solution that I find elegant (but haven't tried personally) is the Abus Nutfix (if there are similar products, I'm not aware of them, and it can also be used for seat tubes). The way it works is that you can only remove the wheel if the bike lies horizontally, so if you bike is attached vertically, there's no way to get the bike horizontally and then remove the wheel(s). You can secure one or the two wheels, then use your u-lock with the unprotected wheel or just the frame if both wheels are secured.

[EDIT]: the Pinhead product line seems also interesting to secure wheels and other bike components (Thanks Chris H)

Comment: Frame locks seem to be a continental thing - they're rare outside of Europe, so there's a regional cast here.

Comment: So the nutfix prevents you putting the bike on a workstand then taking the wheel off? Nasty

Comment: @ChrisH from what I understood, it's fundamentally a cap on a nut (you use a classical wrench to unfasten the wheel). You can only raise the cap to reveal the nut when the bike is horizontal, but once the cap is raised, you can put the bike vertically. Seems to be a very minor inconvenience to compared to have to carry additional cables and locks to secure the wheels if you have to do that several times per week.

Comment: If the cap stays up for the lift, then maybe.  If it's easily jogged, no.  But I use Pinhead anyway

Comment: I didn't know about Pinhead, I added it in the answer. Thx

Comment: According to enwiki, frame locks are common only in The Netherlands and Japan.

Comment: @gerrit: they used to be common here in Germany as well, and you still find them on older bikes.

Comment: If a kind of lock is rare in your area bike Thieves will not know how to break them.

Comment: pinhead is very easy to undo with commonly available tools. @chrish

Comment: @Noise so are cable locks (with cutters). I treat pinhead as comparable to a light cable as a secondary measure securing components. Even track nuts provide some delay compared to QRs for protecting a wheel

Comment: In other words they'll hold off an opportunist and if your wheels are nice enough to attract a determined thief, your frame is probably nice enough for someone with an angle grinder

Answer (score 1):

It is as if answering "If you have to cut your arm or your leg, what will you choose?" There is no right answer, I am afraid.

The bicycle is unusable with only one wheel, so having any of them stolen means you walk home, and have to buy a new wheel before you can use it again.

The front wheel is cheaper, but is also usually easier to remove if not locked. For a seasoned bicycle thief, the difference in time to finish the move is negligible.

Comment: A bicycle missing the front wheel is easier to walk home than one missing the rear wheel

Comment: If everyone else locks up leaving their front wheel vulnerable, locking up leaving the back vulnerable would seem more attractive to thieves (there are always people who leave the frame vulnerable even for expensive bikes)

Comment: Lots of people have dirt cheap bikes and it's no more than a minor inconvenience to replace a wheel. Comparing it to losing an arm or a leg is really absurd, my bike is not a precious mechanical child, it's a way to get to work.

Comment: @ChrisH yeah... though I also often see bikes where just the front wheel is chained to the rack, nothing else. So bike thieves probably have enough use for sparse front wheels already!

Comment: @leftaroundabout I know, there was a lovely steel road bike locked up just by a cheap cable lock on a QR front wheel next to my battered hybrid with big locks recently.  My size too.  It survived a whole working day outside the station, at least.

Comment: I recently saw a bike (parking)rack with a front wheel locked to it and a bike without a front wheel. Looked like someone had combined the parts not well locked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're parking in a way that the bike is in danger, perhaps don't park there.  See if you can store your bike inside, somewhere better.

If you have absolutely no choice, then lock both wheels to the frame and to an immovable object by taking the front wheel off the bike and attaching it to your lock.

Getting a second lock is also a practical solution, though it means carrying twice the weight in locks.   If you routinely park in places like this, swapping a QR wheel axle for a solid one with nuts can help too.  You will need a ~15mm spanner in your toolkit for puncture repairs.   There are fancy wheel nuts that need special spanner tools, but overall effectiveness is debatable.

Comment: For a lot of bikes this answer is overkill, and it sort of ignores the premise of the question. Sometimes, replacing a wheel is annoying, but not a disaster.

Comment: @Clumsycat err replacing a stolen wheel/tyre is annoying and costly, and will also mean phoning for a pickup or a walk home plus inconvenience until a replacement is sourced.  I guess it ultimately depends where OP parks and the risk level.

Comment: Exactly how annoying and expensive is something only OP can know. If their whole bike costs £40, and their work is 20 mins on foot, then it's not really a big deal. Plus, it's a much rarer occurrence if your bike is cheep. Point is, there are circumstances where only locking one wheel is reasonable, and OP is the only one with the information to make that judgement, so I think we should take them at their word when they say they only want to lock one wheel.

Comment: No need for a spanner to patch a tube, just leave the wheel in place.

Comment: @Willeke fair enough - I tend to swap the whole tube rather than patching on the roadside, which requires removing the wheel from the bike.   Patching would be my last resort once I've run out of tubes, and pulling the sticker-patches out of my firstaid kit.

Comment: I now prefer to swap tubes as well but my current rides are set up for that, but it is not that hard to patch with the wheel in place. And with proper tires flats are quite uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

I think that generally does not matter because the lock is more to prevent somebody to jump on and quickly ride away. Just do not use a cheap lock that can be cut away in a matter of seconds.

Regardless of how do you lock, lots of parts still remain accessible and removable. But not all thieves are interested in parts and non-rideable bicycles.

Answer (score 0):

If the front wheel is easy to remove (i.e. has a quick release) then it's generally fairly easy to remove it, place it beside the back wheel and lock both and the frame to some sort of post using standard bike locks.

Otherwise, I'd use a good solid D lock or similar to lock the back wheel and frame to the post (you must always ensure the lock goes around the frame so that thieves cannot remove the back wheel and take every but it! Then use a cheaper/lighter chain/cable lock to lock the front wheel to the frame.

Also if the seat has a quick release - remove it and take it with you. And remember to remove anything removable like a computer - I lost a few computers and at least one seat when I used to commute to university many years back.

Comment: Your tip about removing the front wheel if it has a quick release is good, but already covered in Tim's answer https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/79306/32271 the rest of the answer requires two locks, which is not what the question asked.

Comment: @Clumsycat Where in the question does it exclude the use of two locks? Sure it says they have one but that doesn't mean they're not willing to buy a second cheap one for the front wheel?

Comment: The question states OP has one single U lock available, and is asking about which wheel is "more" important.    @Clumsycat feel free to add an answer to the question.